# How to use PostgreSQL JSONB_SET() to create new deep object element

Tags: postgresql, jsonb, postgresql-9.6

I must be missing something... seems `JSONB_SET()` is not working as [advertised](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-json.html)?

```
SELECT JSONB_SET(
    '{"k1": {"value": "v1"}}',
    '{k2,value}',
    '"v2"',
    TRUE
);
```

Results in:

```
----+------------------------
    | jsonb_set
    | jsonb
----+------------------------
  1 | {"k1": {"value": "v1"}}
----+------------------------
```

I was expecting `{"k1": {"value": "v1"}, "k2": {"value": "v2"}}`
I also tried `FALSE` as the fourth parameter in case it was reversed or something.

I am using PostgreSQL 9.6.4

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The document says:

> jsonb_set(target jsonb, path text[], new_value jsonb[, create_missing
>   boolean])

In your example, the second parameter - `'{k2,value}'` is the search path, but since the first path is `k2` that does not exist, results to NULL *before* `value` could be added/replaced.

In simple terms – jsonb_set is not meant to build entire JSON document the way you tried using search path, but to add or replace *single* key/value.

If you want to add/replace entirely new set of JSON like that you can use `||` (concatenate) operator instead like that:

```
-- Add example:
SELECT $${"k1": {"value": "v1"}}$$::jsonb || $${ "k2": { "value": "v2"}}$$::jsonb;
                    ?column?
------------------------------------------------
 {"k1": {"value": "v1"}, "k2": {"value": "v2"}}
(1 row)

-- Replace example
SELECT $${"k1": {"value": "v1"}}$$::jsonb || $${ "k1": { "value": "v2"}}$$::jsonb;
        ?column?
-------------------------
 {"k1": {"value": "v2"}}
(1 row)
```

**OR**

You can use `jsonb_set()` like that instead:

```
SELECT JSONB_SET(
    '{"k1": {"value": "v1"}}',
    '{k2}',
    '{"value": "v2"}',
    TRUE
);
                   jsonb_set
------------------------------------------------
 {"k1": {"value": "v1"}, "k2": {"value": "v2"}}
(1 row)
```

Comment: Thanks - I think I can use the 2nd option. The value `v2` is coming from another query, but I can json-ize it with `JSON_BUILD_OBJECT('value', (QUERY))`, right?

Comment: Yes if the query results only that single value preferably as json.

Comment: `||` doesn't really work if there are other values except `k2.value`, i.e. lets imagine we want to modify a value in a nested object with might or might not exist. If it exists and create other values we are gonna remove them with this approach

Answer (score 5):

I just faced the same issue and created a simple postgres-function for it.
It **may not be the fastest solution** and might especially be slow for deep inserts, but so far works fine for me!

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION jsonb_deep_set(curjson jsonb, globalpath text[], newval jsonb) RETURNS jsonb AS
$$
  BEGIN
    IF curjson is null THEN
      curjson := '{}'::jsonb;
    END IF;
    FOR index IN 1..ARRAY_LENGTH(globalpath, 1) LOOP
      IF curjson #> globalpath[1:index] is null THEN
        curjson := jsonb_set(curjson, globalpath[1:index], '{}');
      END IF;
    END LOOP;
    curjson := jsonb_set(curjson, globalpath, newval);
    RETURN curjson;
  END;
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

Relacing `jsonb` with `json` makes it also work for json objects.

Comment: A similar Gist for this logic can be seen [here](https://gist.github.com/villelahdenvuo/5b1fbbf3f22853475bba14f8833faada). (as well as [my alternative](https://gist.github.com/villelahdenvuo/5b1fbbf3f22853475bba14f8833faada#gistcomment-3923861), which avoids the need to create a new function)

Answer (score 2):

To achieve "safe value-setting" of deeply-nested fields (without having to create a new PostgreSQL function in the database), I use the following pattern: (as first [mentioned here](https://gist.github.com/villelahdenvuo/5b1fbbf3f22853475bba14f8833faada#gistcomment-3923871))

```
UPDATE "myTable" SET "myField" =
  jsonb_set(COALESCE("myField", '{}'), array['depth1'],
  jsonb_set(COALESCE("myField"->'depth1', '{}'), array['depth2'],
  jsonb_set(COALESCE("myField"->'depth1'->'depth2', '{}'), array['depth3'],
  jsonb_set(COALESCE("myField"->'depth1'->'depth2'->'depth3', '{}'), array['depth4'],
  '"newValue"'
)))) WHERE "id" = 'myRowID' RETURNING *
```

And for those who may dislike the deeply-nested nature of the calls above, here is an alternative:

```
UPDATE "myTable" SET "myField" = jsonb_set(
  CASE
    WHEN "myField" IS NULL THEN '{"depth1": {"depth2": {"depth3": {}}}}'
    WHEN "myField"->'depth1' IS NULL THEN jsonb_set("myField", array['depth1'], '{"depth2": {"depth3": {}}}')
    WHEN "myField"->'depth1'->'depth2' IS NULL THEN jsonb_set("myField", array['depth1','depth2'], '{"depth3": {}}')
    WHEN "myField"->'depth1'->'depth2'->'depth3' IS NULL THEN jsonb_set("myField", array['depth1','depth2','depth3'], '{}')
    ELSE "myField"
  END,
  array['depth1','depth2','depth3','depth4'],
  '"newValue"'
) WHERE "id" = 'myRowID' RETURNING *
```